# What is the meaning of saying that Cron's default shell is some shell (say, Bourne)?

Tags: cron, terminology

I grasp Cron as a program that one runs above its own default shell (or a new started shell session on top of the whatever default shell) and has its own syntax and rules.

I don't think it's correct to say that Cron itself is a shell. I have understood that Cron uses some shell which by default, in most systems --- Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`).

What is the meaning of saying that Cron's default shell is some shell (say, Bourne)?

Comment: Yes, cron runs the commands specified in crontab through a shell. [The man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/cron/crontab.5.en.html) (for Vixie cron in Debian) says: _"The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab file."_ Is there something in particular about it that you're asking?

Comment: I don't have any particular thing left to ask about this besides, why not make Cron itself a shell?

Comment: About the phrase; I meant to a situation were a user changed the default shell of Cron (utilized to run commands) from Bourne, to anything else --- Bash/ksh/zsh etc.

Comment: @ilkkachu I now recalled that any Cron command is actually comprised of two parts --- one is the Cron part (with all its syntax) and the second is the Shell part (with all its syntax) and therefore it is indeed good to let the user choose what shell to work with and not make Cron itself a standalone shell. I have learned about it in 2015, I didn't work with Cron since about then so I misrecalled this for a moment...

Comment: "why not make cron itself a shell?"  because cron's job is to schedule tasks, not to be a shell interpreter.   Setting SHELL= is not a very common thing to do, but is sometimes useful - e.g. if /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash and you want cron to run jobs with /bin/dash instead.

Answer (score 0):

I now recalled that any Cron command is actually comprised of two parts --- one is the Cron part (with all its syntax) and the second is the Shell part (with all its syntax) and therefore it is indeed good to let the user choose what shell to work with and not make Cron itself a standalone shell. I have learned about it in 2015, I didn't work with Cron since about then so I misrecalled this for a moment.